# PowerShell Get-Content on multiple unknow files from multiple directories and sub directories

Tags: file, powershell, subdirectory

I did the following script in PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content text\text.txt).replace('ABC', 'abc') | Set-Content text\text.txt
```

it works as expected...
it reads the contents of a file and replaces a particular character sequence by another seguency...
but, I need that script identify multiple files with different names in others possibles subdirectories of the same initial directory.

```
dir01\file_name.abc
dir01\filename.def
dir01\dir02\fi-le_na-me.ghi
dir01\dor02\fi_le-na_me.jkl
dir01\dir02\dir03\f-i-l-e_n-a-m-e.mno
etc...
```

I do not know which will be the names of the files nor the directories too!

In msdos I use the following expression to go from file to file:

```
for %%F in (*.*) do ("winRAR.exe" "%%F")
```

this batch, compresses file by file... its only a sample!

I do not know how to identifying file by file in PowerShel... Could someone help me with that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Get-ChildItem` and pipe the output into your command. You can tell `Get-ChildItem` to recurse directories using `-recurse` and only return files with `-File`:

```
Get-ChildItem dir01 -recurse -file | 
    foreach{(Get-Content $_.FullName).replace('ABC', 'abc') | Set-Content $_.FullName}
```

Comment: thank you very much zdan, works perfectly...  I was thinkig if it would be possible to replace two strings at the same time?
        'ABC', 'abc' and 'DEF', 'def'